# EF Core DbSet's "Select" Extension still show other columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm starting to learn **ASP and EF Core** and currently working on a Web Service.

I already have the following:

1. **Menu** Model that has 3 variables/columns
2. DBContext containing **DbSet<'Menu'>**
3. **MenuController** that has HTTPGet Method

**Inside the HTTPGet Method is:**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public List<Menu> Get()
    {
       return db.Menus.Select(p => new Menu
        {
            m_menu = p.m_menu
        }).Distinct().ToList();
    }
```

My goal is to select only 1 column instead of 3 columns and distinct it. So I use the **.Select** extension for me to show only 1 specific column which is **m_menu**.

As I call MenuController, the HTTPGet still response or show all the columns instead of only 1 column(**m_menu**). The sample result **[JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWBVR.png)** shows other columns with **null** value and only **m_menu** has a value.

I read some related problems and suggested to Serialize the JSON but still not help me with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Becase your metod returns `List<Menu>` and `Menu` has 3 properties: `m_id`, `m_menu` and `s_menu`.
If you want to return only one column, you cand return `List<string>`:

```
[HttpGet]
public List<string> Get()
{
   return db.Menus.Select(p => p.m_menu ).Distinct().ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Man! I have a question if its okay. What if 2 columns? Should I still use <string> or create another Model that has only 2 columns?

Comment: You can return Tuple or anonymous type, depending on your needs, just like in classic EF. For most things you do not need to limit search results to Core version.

Comment: @PTwr Thanks Man! I tried Tuple/Anonymous Type and It works!